# PHP Combining variables in a $_SESSION but receiving Undefined variable on call

Tags: php, session, variables

I have this bit of code in my script, the `SESSION` was started at the top of the page - just for your info.

```
$_SESSION['PlanType'] // set in form
$_SESSION['ReceipientNum'] // Set Earlier in Form Handler
if ($_POST['action'] == 'AddAnother') {  // If Add Another button was selected
    $_SESSION[${'PlanType'.$_SESSION['ReceipientNum']}] = $_SESSION['PlanType'];
    echo $_SESSION[${'PlanType'.$_SESSION['ReceipientNum']}]; // this was line 372
    exit;

    } else if ($_POST['action'] == 'Review') {

        //Do stuff
    }
```

When i try and echo the variable I am getting -

> Notice: Undefined variable: PlanType1 in .../shipping.php on line 372

But then follows with the correct value that was set. Has this got something to do with the `{}` within the `$_SESSION`?

Cheers in adavance

Comment: Please show what values are in your session array. Use `print_r()`

Comment: `But then follows with the correct value that was set. ` Please clarify this statement. is PHP error telling you the variable `$_SESSION['PlanType1']` has not been set and *then* showing you that the variable does exist?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
${'PlanType'.$_SESSION['ReceipientNum']}='';
$_SESSION[${'PlanType'.$_SESSION['ReceipientNum']}] = $_SESSION['PlanType'];
    echo $_SESSION[${'PlanType'.$_SESSION['ReceipientNum']}]; // this was line 372
```

Comment: Hi Nishanth, tried that and I can understand the logic but it returned nothing. Thanks heaps anyway. :)